# Views table with two columns

Tags: views, theming

I have 3 fields.

I've set them with view table, set their labels and they are displaying in this order:

field1 label      field2 label    field3 label

field1 value   field2 value  field3 value

They are in three columns.

How can I set them in this order like on the screenshot?

[image]

Comment: take a look at https://drupal.org/project/tablegroup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Views Flipped Table](https://drupal.org/project/views_flipped_table) module.

> This module provides a views table style with rows and columns
>   flipped. This is useful for views showing few entities with many
>   fields, such as product comparison.

Answer (score 4):

I think [Views Flipped Table](https://drupal.org/project/views_flipped_table) will help you.

Comment: please add the description, when you post the answer like the above post